# Randomizing an array with a set percentage of components

Tags: java, arrays, random, percentage, shuffle

I'm trying to create an array of 30 elements, with set percentages of how many of each element there should be. (i.e. 40% should be "a", 20% should be "b", 20% should be "c" and so on) The end result should be a randomized array of these components.

We're probably not allowed to use Collection.shuffle(), as we haven't covered that in class.

Help on how to approach this? Is there an alternate way to shuffle an array after inserting the elements in order with a loop? Or is there a way to randomly choose a component to insert? Thanks.

Comment: Why not have a pool of indices and randomly pick from your pool of indices to insert to?

Comment: and also, did you look up "shuffle algorithm" in Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple approach (without providing a homework solution)

1. Fill the collection with the items in the required proportions, in order.
2. Shuffle the collection (using any appropriate shuffle algorithm)

Comment: Got it, thanks. Just got thrown off by the percentages for some reason.